# Использование прокси Telethon

Tags: python, telethon, прокси

Проблема заключается с авторизацией с прокси telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import python_socks
import asyncio

asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.SelectorEventLoop())

api_id = None
api_hash = None

proxy = {
    'proxy_type': python_socks.ProxyType.HTTP,
    'addr': '',
    'port': 1111,
    'username': '',
    'password': ''
}

client = TelegramClient("", api_id, api_hash, proxy=proxy,
                    device_model="iPhone 13 Pro Max",
                    system_version="14.8.1",
                    app_version="8.4",
                    lang_code="en",
                    system_lang_code="en-US")


async def main():
    me = await client.get_me()
    print(me)


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

при вводе сюда валидных данных(прокси и сессия) и использовании
`asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.SelectorEventLoop())`

выходит такая ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же закомментировать `asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.SelectorEventLoop())`
то получается:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если не использовать прокси то все работает как обычно, с чем может быть связана моя проблема?
Я использовал и PySocks и python_socks проблема та же, когда передавал прокси в виде кортежа они просто игнорировались.
Версия питона 3.11